# How to get data everyday's eight AM.?

Tags: mysql

MySQL database, I have a table which contains some column. First column is datatime type, like "2016-03-01 08:00:00", "2016-03-02 08:00:00".

What should i do to get everyday's 8 AM. from this table?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. As it stands this question isn't very clear. Could you post some actual table definitions and some sample data along with expected output? You can [edit](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/134049/edit) your question to add additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE TIME(dt) = '08:00:00'` is another way to filter on exactly 8am.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to return rows where the time is 8.00:

```
select       ...
from         a_table
where        hour(some_column) = 8
and          minute(some_column) = 0
```

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-hour-function.php
http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/minute.php